# If $(E_n,\mathcal E_n)$ is a measurable space, can we show that $\left.\sigma(\mathcal E_1\cup\mathcal E_2)\right|_{E_1}=\mathcal E_1$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(E_n,\mathcal E_n)$ be a measurable space for $n=1,2$ and \begin{align}E&:=E_1\cup E_2;\\\mathcal E&:=\sigma(\mathcal E_1\cup\mathcal E_2).\end{align}

I would like to show

1. $\left.\mathcal E\right|_{E_1}=\mathcal E_1$.
2. If $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ is a measurable space and $X:\Omega\to E_1$ is $(\mathcal A,\mathcal E_1)$-measurable, then $X$ is $(\mathcal A,\mathcal E)$-measurable.

Regarding 1.: Since $E_1\in\mathcal E$, $$\left.\mathcal E\right|_{E_1}=\{B\cap E_1:B\in\mathcal E\}=\{B\in\mathcal E:B\subseteq E_1\}\tag1.$$ By $(1)$ and $\mathcal E_1\subseteq\mathcal E$, $$\mathcal E_1\subseteq\left.\mathcal E\right|_{E_1}\tag2.$$ But how do we obtain the other direction?

Regarding 2.: Let $B\in\mathcal E$. We need to show $\{X\in B\}\in\mathcal A$. We can clearly write $\{X\in B\}=\{X\in B\cap E_1\}$ and, by definition, $B\cap E_1\in\left.\mathcal E\right|_{E_1}$. So, if we can show (1.), then we obtain the claim.

Answer (score 0):

I assume $E_1 \cap E_2 = \emptyset$. Then $\sigma(\mathcal{E}_1 \cup \mathcal{E}_2)|_{E_1} = \sigma((\mathcal{E}_1 \cup \mathcal{E}_2)|_{E_1}) = \sigma(\mathcal{E}_1) = \mathcal{E}_1$. Here I used the general identity $\sigma(A)|_{B} = \sigma(A|_B)$, valid for all sets $A, B$. This identity follows from the identity $X^{-1}(\sigma(A)) = \sigma(X^{-1}(A))$ for any function $X$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do we need to assume that $E_1$ and $E_2$ are disjoint? Or can we do this with no restriction (by treating $E_1$ and $E_2$ as disjoint, even when $E_1$ and $E_2$ are both $\mathbb R^d$, for example).

Comment: "This identity follows from ...": Is this with regard to the second question? If so, how does this identity help to show the desired claim? And doesn't (2.) immediately follow from (1.) as I've described in the question?

Comment: No I was only answering your first question.